# How to install CUPS 1.6.3 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, printing, 13.10

We have a CUPS server 1.3 and my freshly installed Ubuntu 13.04 PC has CUPS client 1.6.2. They are incompatible.

On the CUPS web server I saw that [CUPS 1.6.3](http://www.cups.org/articles.php?L276+TFAQ+Q) has fixed the issue.

"CUPS 1.6.3 fixes some compatibility issues with servers running CUPS 1.3.12 or older..."

So I would like to replace CUPS 1.6.2 with 1.6.3 on my Ubuntu 13.04 PC. I guess Ubuntu 13.10 will have CUPS 1.6.3 and later I would like to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10. I would thus prefer avoiding installing CUPS 1.6.3 manually to avoid any troubles.

Is there a way to install CUPS version 1.6.3 using a ppa or something like that ?

Comment: You could try getting the updated package from 13.10 repo
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/1.6.3-1ubuntu2 although there might always be version dependencies to grind gears.

Comment: I tried to manually install them but the pakage cups-common is reported missing. And it is not visible in the package list.

Comment: Uhm, at least I see it, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/cups-common_1.6.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb

Comment: @chmike how about this one: https://launchpad.net/~till-kamppeter/+archive/ppa I didn't test it myself though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link for the ppa for cups version 1.6.3-1ubuntu2

[Cups PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups)

Comment: This is the same link provided by shookees. It's not a ppa url. Excuse my inexperience but how do I configure apt-get to download cups 1.6.3 for me ?